# How to position images at the same spot all devices?

Tags: android

I need a picture of her at a certain point I show an image.

The problem here is in a different device, the image was placed in different locations. Please do.

Grateful

Update:
screenshot Link:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/101697430014326112229/albums/6082231126936274529/6082231131411412050?sqi=115801382199762646242&sqsi=35f13185-45b3-4a47-a0fd-7303cf6aa1c1

Comment: Can you show code, resources file? Some screenshot if possible?

Comment: @MysticMagic do you even understand what he is asking? `I need a picture of her`, so romantic :)

Comment: @BlazeTama what I understood is, he needs to show some image at some fix position. Not concerned with whose :)

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the position of an element (image) and it appears in different places depending on the device you may considering resetting css:

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/